# How to construct Expressions manually in EF6 to match the same output?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I tried to construct Expression tree manually. It could be helpful when EF can't translate expression to sql or you need to construct dynamic the query. Whatever in my opinion this help a lot to understand what is going under the hood. 
I have tried to construct simple "where" query. Which in my opinion is the same as lambda constructed. However, sql output differs.

**Manual constructed Expression:**

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Transfer));
var manualExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Transfer, bool>>(
    body: Expression.AndAlso(
        left: Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, nameof(Transfer.DestinationFromId)), Expression.Constant(transferDto.DestinationFromId, typeof(Int32))),
        right: Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, nameof(Transfer.DestinationToId)), Expression.Constant(transferDto.DestinationToId, typeof(Int32)))
    ), 
    parameters: param
);

var result = await DataContext.Transfers.Where(manualExpr).ToListAsync();
```

Sql output:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Time] AS [Time], 
    [Extent1].[DestinationFromId] AS [DestinationFromId], 
    [Extent1].[PassengerCount] AS [PassengerCount], 
    [Extent1].[DestinationToId] AS [DestinationToId]
    FROM [dbo].[Transfers] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (13 = [Extent1].[DestinationFromId]) AND (11 = [Extent1].[DestinationToId])
```

**Lambda (function) constructed Expression:**

```
Expression<Func<Transfer, bool>> funcExpr = (t) => t.DestinationFromId == transferDto.DestinationFromId && t.DestinationToId == transferDto.DestinationToId;
var res = await DataContext.Transfers.Where(funcExpr).ToListAsync();
```

Sql output

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Number] AS [Number], 
    [Extent1].[Time] AS [Time], 
    [Extent1].[DestinationFromId] AS [DestinationFromId], 
    [Extent1].[PassengerCount] AS [PassengerCount]
    [Extent1].[DestinationToId] AS [DestinationToId]
    FROM [dbo].[Transfers] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[DestinationFromId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[DestinationToId] = @p__linq__1)
```

As you can observe output is different for where statement in sql. Manually expression uses inlined values. And the lambda uses property parameters which open possibility for SQLServer cache the query.
Am I constructed query wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build the same expression you need to change your code a bit:

```
var manualExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Transfer, bool>>(
    body: Expression.AndAlso(
        left: Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, nameof(Transfer.DestinationFromId)),
           // instead of using direct constant value,
           // we build expression transferDto.DestinationFromId
           Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Constant(transferDto), nameof(transferDto.DestinationFromId))),
        right: Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, nameof(Transfer.DestinationToId)),
           // instead of using direct constant value,
           // we build expression transferDto.DestinationToId
           Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Constant(transferDto), nameof(transferDto.DestinationToId)))
    ),
    parameters: param
);
```

Your current expression is the same as:

```
Expression<Func<Transfer, bool>> funcExpr = (t) => t.DestinationFromId == 11 && t.DestinationToId == 13)
```

which is not exactly the same as expression you are after.

Comment: As I understood `PropertyOrField` expression is the specific way of EF to represent the query parameters of an SQL?

Comment: @unsafePtr not really. I use `PropertyOrField` but it can be just `Property` in this case (so, the same you use in other places). When you access properties of external objects (`transferDto` in this case) - EF use parameters for that. But when you use literals (`DestinationFromId == 11`) - it will not and also use literals.

Comment: Can you give an example with only `Property` usage, please.

Comment: Just replace `PropertyOrField` with `Property` in the above code, no other changes needed.

Comment: sorry for annoying from my side. But what if we need to change value before of constructing expression tree. I try to check if the day before of supplied day in parameters is greater or equal. After some experiments I achieved this in following way `Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(new TransferDto { Time = transferDto.Time.AddDays(-1) }), nameof(transferDto.Time))`. This is all because of `Property` expression. In constructor you should specify the name of property. Am I doing it right or there is a beautifully way to write it?

Comment: And how would you write that without manually constructing expressions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160944/discussion-between-unsafeptr-and-evk).